# android Admob and startApp

Tags: android, admob, startapp, google-ad-manager

I have an app on playstore https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.advocosoftwares.colorbook. I have used startApp in first release version. Now for next version I am trying to add AdMob rewarded video ad in the same app. I am getting the issue while implementing it. I have followed the complete procedure from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_frcK8lYnX8 but onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad() method is called showing error code 3, I tried with both the sample id as well as created new Id for project but same error code as a result. I did the same procedure in other app where it works fine. Just having the issue in this app. Please help me out.

Comment: can you show the code .

Answer (score 0):

[Error Code 3](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL) means no fills from the mediated ad network.

Try again by enabling only test ads from startApp and see if that works. 
You can also use [this sample app](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_ZafC3Djh1ReE55Nngwb2FtVnc) to test you ad unit id.